# I need understand this Kotlin while loop result

Tags: kotlin, while-loop

Why the result is 5050?

```
fun main() {
    var sum = 0
    var i = 1
    while (i<=100) {
        sum += i
        i++
    }
    println(sum)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn how to use the debugger, which will let you step through this code line by line and see all the variables values. You'll see that it makes quite perfect sense.

Comment: What other result would you expect from this?

Comment: This code prints the sum of numbers from 1 to 100, ie sum of values of `i` from 1 to 100 (1+2+3+...+100). Is there anything else that you were expecting? Would be better to rephrase the question with what exactly you need to understand with it and what you were expecting.

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes it should be 100 but I got the result of 5050 and I want to understand the logic of this result.

Comment: “Yes it should be 100” — _Why_ do you think the sum should be 100? It seems to me that the program is working as intended; maybe this question should be on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I think the i++ is being missed in your reading of the code.

Comment: @IlkinAhmadJr. it cannot be 100, as the sum is (1+2+3+..+100) = 5050. Could you explain how you are expecting it to be 100? What is the problem statement that you're trying to solve with the code? Or is it just that you thought it should print 100?

Comment: @MadhuBhat I'm just new in coding. I just want to learn the logic for a good understanding.

Comment: To make this code print 100, you would not add the i value to the sum each time. Instead you would just print the sum value after the loop. The logic of this code is saying, each time we increment i, add it to the previous value of sum, and then repeart until i == 100, which will add up to a total of 5050

Comment: @BenjaminCharais That's it. Thanks

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the result of your loop is (100+1)*50 (thats how you sum a interval) which results in 5050, the value of i is changing every loop and being added to the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code works as follows:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var sum = 0      // start with value 0
    var i = 1        // let i is 1
    while (i<=100) { // work until i is less than 100
        sum += i     // calculate `sum + i = ?` then put it back to `sum` again
        i++          // increment i by 1
    }
    println(sum)     // show me the result
}
```

You can try it manually with a paper and pencil. Try with `while (i<=10)`. You will get 55 as result.